# Append to csv file column-wise under one header

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

Coding in Python 2.7. I have a csv file already present called input.csv. In that file we have 3 headers — Filename, Category, Version — under which certain values already exist.

I want to know how I can reopen the csv file and input only one value multiple times under the "Version" column such that whatever was written under "Version" gets overwritten by the new input.

So suppose under the "Version" column I had 3 inputs in 3 rows:

```
VERSION
  55
  66
  88
```

It gets rewritten by my new input 10 so it will look like:

```
VERSION
  10
  10
  10
```

I know normally we input csv row-wise but this time around I just want to input column wise under that specific header "Version".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

With `pandas`, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['VERSION'] = 10
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Solution 2: If there are multiple rows (and you only want first 3), then you can use:

```
df.loc[df.index < 3, ['VERSION']] = 10
```

instead of:

```
df['VERSION'] = 10
```

Comment: I want to make sure that it gets inputed for the number of rows filename or Category has: So if filename or Category has 4 rows the Version should also have 4 rows. If it has 10 rows version should also have 10 rows

Comment: @RidwanChowdhury , the first solution should work then.